# jQuery slider, handle faster than background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

im using jQuery ui slider and i got a problem

Here's a picture of 2 bars that shows what i mean:
[image]

As you can see the handle is much faster than the background, how can i fix so the background keeps up with the handle?

Here is my code:

Javascript:

```
$( ".slider" ).slider({
    orientation: "horizontal",
    animate: 1,
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    value: 60,
    create: function( event, ui ) {
        var slider = $(this).find(".progress-bar").data("valuenow"); 
        $(this).slider("value", slider);
    },
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        var test = $(this).find(".progress-bar");
        var splitter = $(this).find(".progress-bar").attr("class").split(' '); 
        if (ui.value < 30) { 
            $(test).removeClass(splitter[1]).addClass("progress-bar-danger");
        }
        else if (ui.value > 30 && ui.value < 60) { 
            $(test).removeClass(splitter[1]).addClass("progress-bar-warning");
        }
        else { 
            $(test).removeClass(splitter[1]).addClass("progress-bar-success");
        }
        $(test).css("width", ui.value + '%');
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="progress slider"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" data-valuenow="60" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;"></div></div>
```

Forgot to mention that i use bootstrap for the progressbar

Comment: The code you posted doesn't produce the image: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dzoum9j7/

Comment: Sorry forgot, im using bootstrap and their progressbar, thanks for noticing that :)